# Does @Test(enabled = false) work for a class in TestNG?

Tags: class, annotations, testng

From the TestNG doc I can see that `(enabled = false)` can be applied to a class or method. But it seems it only works when applied to a *method*.

Anybody seen the same, found a solution?

Comment: For the benefit of readers, it cannot be `Enabled` and must be `enabled`.

Answer (score 14):

It seems to work for me:

```java
@Test(enabled = false)
public class B {

    public void btest1() {
        System.out.println("B.btest1");
    }

}
```

**Result:**

```java
===============================================
SingleSuite
Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Changing *false* to *true*:

```java
B.btest1

===============================================
SingleSuite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

---

### Possible reason

Here is what might be tripping you (hard to tell since you didn't provide any code):

```java
@Test(enabled = false)
public class B {

    @Test
    public void btest1() {
        System.out.println("B.btest1");
    }

}
```

This case will run the test because by repeating the `@Test` annotation on the method, you are also **overriding the `enabled` attribute** to its *default* value, which is `true`.

The solution is to reiterate `enabled=false` at the method level:

```java
@Test(enabled = false)
public class B {

    @Test(enabled = false)
    public void btest1() {
        System.out.println("B.btest1");
    }

}
```

I'm aware it's a bit counterintuitive but it's necessary in order to be consistent in the way *method* annotations can override *class* annotations.

Comment: Just discovered that it's best to single out individual tests by using the command line usage of `test -groups` or `test <module>:<type>.<method>`