# How to disable entire unit test in TestNG?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, testng

This is what I can do in JUnit:

```
import org.junit.*;
@Ignore
public class FooTest {
  //
}
```

and the entire class will be ignored. How can I do the same in TestNG?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

I believe what you want is:

```
@Test(enabled=false)
public class FooTest {
  //
}
```

(You can apply the @Test annotation to the class, as well as to methods individually.)

The [TestNG documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html) has a comprehensive list of the supported annotations, and also describes exclusion/inclusion of tests by group if that's of any interest. Here's a quote from the relevant section:

> @Test Marks a class or a method as
>   part of the test.
>
> *...(snip)...*
>
> enabled: Whether methods on this class/method are enabled.

**EDIT**:
Ignoring a class by applying `@Test(enabled=false)` is apparently buggy functionality in some versions of TestNG according to [this defect](http://jira.opensymphony.com/browse/TESTNG-434) that was raised against TestNG.

Comment: That's the correct answer: it will mark all the public methods of the class as disabled. Note that putting a @Test on a method will re-enable that method, and that method only. Let me know if you're seeing something different.

Comment: Apparently, others have also had issues with @Test when applied at class level. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149147/does-testenabled-false-work-for-a-class-in-testng).

Comment: Perhaps it's a bug in some versions of TestNG.

Comment: Confirmed: it *is* a bug, according to [this Google cache of the OpenSymphony bug page](http://jira.opensymphony.com/browse/TESTNG-434) that was tracking it.

Comment: The nice thing about the JUnit @Ignore is that you can specify the reason why you are ignoring the test.  Is there any way to do this in TestNG other than leaving a comment that someone might forget to delete when they re-enable the test?

Comment: Yeah, I had the same problem adding it to the class level. I had to place the enabled=false in ALL tests.