# How to exclude class in TestNG

Tags: java, xml, testng

I have a test suite called Test.XML. If I want to exclude any one class, how can I do that?

Here is the **Test.XML**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
 
<suite name="TestAll">
 
    <test name="test1">
        <classes>
            <class name="test.LoginOneReports" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="test2">
        <classes>
            <class name="test.OEPR_DefaultTab" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="test3">
        <classes>
            <class name="test.OEPR_InternalvsExternalTab" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: Already asked in [How to exclude class in TestNG](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12157846/214178)

Answer (score 0):

You can't explicitly exclude classes in TestNG.xml. Please refer to more detailed answer for question [How to exclude class in TestNG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12171785/214178).

Answer (score 0):

Mention all the class names inside <classes> including the ones that should not be run. And, inside the class that should be excluded, use  and <exclude name =.* />. It will exclude all the tests from this class and run all the other classes.