# How to exclude some selenium test cases from the package?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, testng

I have a test cast package setup to run. However, there are some test cases in the package I want to exclude. How should I do it if I do not change the code? as far as I know testng does not have feature that to exclude single test case inside the package.

Comment: What language and testing framework you are using?

Answer (score 1):

As you are using TestNg, the easiest option is adding (enabled = false) after the @Test annotation.

```
@Test(enabled = false)
public void yourTestMethod() throws Exception {
//your code here
}
```

See [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations) for information on annotations.

Comment: what if I do not change the code, how can accomplish that changing testng.xml?

Answer (score 0):

```
You can exclude methods and groups in TestNG,see [here.][1]


  [1]: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-xml

I am able to exclude method using following code :

<classes>
      <class name="scripts.CheckTest" />
      <class name="scripts.Day1" >
          <methods>
              <exclude name="verifyMobilePageTitle" />
          </methods>
      </class>
</classes>
```

Comment: Hi i am not running the classes but the package. for example:               <test name="French-chrome">
  <parameter name="language" value="French" />
  <packages>
   <package name="com.aaa.testscripts.*"/>
  </packages>
  </test>                                                                                                and I want to disable one test case from this package because it is failing. how should I do that?

Comment: You can see following : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12157846/how-to-exclude-class-in-testng