# TestNG @AfterMethod bind to methods of current class

Tags: java, testng

Well, I'm a bit confused.

```
public class GroupDemo {

   @Test()
   public void test1() {
        System.out.println("test1");
   }
}
```

and

```
public class GroupDemoChild extends GroupDemo{

   @Test
   public void atest(){
       System.out.println("atest");
   }

   @AfterMethod
   public void after() {
       System.out.println("after method");
   }
}
```

And what is logical to expect here:

```
test1
atest
after method
```

However I get:

```
test1
after method
atest
after method
```

So `after()` is invoked twice.

How do I run it only after methods of declaring class?

TestNG = 6.8.5;
Java = 1.7

Comment: Call your after method explicitly from @Test?

Comment: It could work, but only if @Test invocationCount=1

Comment: You can `@Override @Test(enabled=false) public void test1() {}` and run both classes separately. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209177/how-to-disable-entire-unit-test-in-testng

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also utilize a custom implementation of the [IInvokedMethodListener](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/IInvokedMethodListener.html) interface along with some custom annotation. Something like:

```
@Listeners({ com.somepackage.MethodInvocationListener.class })
public class GroupDemoChild extends GroupDemo{

   @Test
   @AfterEd
   public void atest(){
       System.out.println("atest");
   }
}

public class MethodInvocationListener implements IInvokedMethodListener {
    @Override
    public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod iInvokedMethod, ITestResult iTestResult) {
        // doNothing
    }

    @Override
    public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod iInvokedMethod, ITestResult iTestResult) {
        if (iInvokedMethod.getTestMethod().getConstructorOrMethod()
                .getMethod().getAnnotation(AfterEd.class) != null) {
                System.out.println("after method");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like it, quite generic

Answer (score 0):

```
@AfterMethod
public void after(Method method) {
    if(method.getDeclaringClass() == this.getClass()) {
        System.out.println("after method"); 
    }
}
```

Is a quick and dirty solution. But can we have anything more for normal people?

Comment: Okay, I accept my own answer since it worked perfectly for launching with tests where invocationCount>1 and does not affect superclasses. **To possible Cedric Beust in this thread**: Could the described behavior be a bug of 6.8.5 ?

Answer (score 0):

In fact current behavior is:

- **test1()**
- *after()*
- **atest()**
- *after()*
- **test1()**

because `@AfterMethod` runs after each `@Test` method in 'current' class hierarchy and if you include class without it again it's not executed.

Solution is to not use `extends GroupDemo` and create more specific/generic classes (basically refactor your test class hierarchy).

Also you can use some attributes in `@AfterMethod` for better flow control (`alwaysRun, groups, etc.`). http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/annotations/AfterMethod.html

Comment: In fact, TestNG documentation does not state that AfterMethod will be run for every method in **hierarchy** up to superclasses. And this seems strange, since e.g. AfterClass works for the lowest instantiated class in hierarchy.

Answer (score -1):

In Testng, `@AfterMethod` will execute after every `@Test` method.

Use `@AfterTest`, this will execute after all `@Test` have been executed.

Comment: Won't work for invocationCount>1, AfterTest is not meant for teardown of specific method, but rather the </test>